# Javascript not replacing string

Tags: javascript

I have a string coming to my WebApp formatted this way:

`GPL.TU01<50;0;100;0;0>`

I have to out put it this way:

```
GPL.TU01
<
50;
0;
100;
0;
0
>
```

This is what I'm using:

```
var GET_result_formatted = GET_result;
global_file_content = GET_result;
GET_result_formatted = GET_result_formatted.replace("<", "\r<\r");
GET_result_formatted = GET_result_formatted.replace(';', ";\r");
GET_result_formatted = GET_result_formatted.replace(">", "\r>");
$('#ModalGPLTextarea').val(GET_result_formatted);
```

But the sad result is this:

```
GPL.TU01
<
50;
0;100;0;0
>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use regex for String.replace for replacing multiple instances.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) only replaces the first occurrence, when a string is passed.
Use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instead, for the `;`:

```
GET_result_formatted = GET_result_formatted.replace("<", "\r<\r");
GET_result_formatted = GET_result_formatted.replace(/;/g, ";\r");
GET_result_formatted = GET_result_formatted.replace(">", "\r>");
```

The `g` in `/;/g` is a "global" flag, that means it will replace *all* occurrences of `;`.

---

These lines can also be shortened a lot, since `.replace` can be chained:

```
var GET_result_formatted = GET_result.replace("<", "\r<\r")
                                     .replace(/;/g, ";\r")
                                     .replace(">", "\r>");
global_file_content = GET_result;
$('#ModalGPLTextarea').val(GET_result_formatted);
```

Notice the missing `;` at the end of the first 2 lines.

Comment: Good answer:) [Here](http://jsmantras.com/blog/String-Methods-search-match-and-replace) is some more stuff on `.replace` and other string methods. Sorry to be a bother, I started on my own answer, but it would've been almost an exact copy of your answer. Do you mind adding something to your answer about `.split` then `.join`? Personally I have seen faster results doing that rather than a `.replace`:)